# Twython using Enterprise Search API

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am trying to scrape tweets from twitter using twython and I want to use enterprise search api for this because I want to define fromDate and toDate parameters.

I couldn't find any way to do it though, and when I try to cursor tweets from this date, It only returns the tweets about 14 days ago from now.

```
twitter = Twython(consumer_token, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
# Search parameters
def search_query(QUERY_TO_BE_SEARCHED):
    """
    QUERY_TO_BE_SEARCHED : text you want to search for 
    """
    df_dict=[]

    results = twitter.cursor(twitter.search, q=QUERY_TO_BE_SEARCHED,fromDate='2019071200',toDate='2019071400',count=100)
    for q in results:
        retweet_count = q['retweet_count']
        favs_count = q['favorite_count']
        date_created = q['created_at']
        text = q['text']
        hashtags = q['entities']['hashtags']
        user_name = '@'+str(q['user']['screen_name'])
        user_mentions = []
        if(len(q['entities']['user_mentions'])!=0):
            for n in q['entities']['user_mentions']:
                user_mentions.append(n['screen_name']) # Mentioned profile names in the tweet
        temp_dict = {'User ID':user_name,'Date':date_created,'Text':text,'Favorites':favs_count,'RTs':retweet_count,
                    'Hashtags':hashtags,'Mentions':user_mentions}
        df_dict.append(temp_dict)

    return pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

that is my code, can you help me improve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure about twython, but as an alternative you can use [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) to use Twitter's Premium Search. [Example](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/premium_search.py) If you really need Enterprise Search, it should be fairly easy to add support for this to the package.